# turn Predicate; How do you append a sublist of reversed elements to a list?

Tags: prolog

turn\3 takes two lists as input, the original, and the toggles. When an element is a member of the toggle, it reverses order for all elements after. I want to know how to reverse the order of part of a list as determined by the toggling of a certain set of elements. An example of how this would work is :

```
?- turn([1,2,3,4,5],[3],L). 
L = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5].

?- turn([1,b,3,5,hello,5,7,z],[5,b,a],L). 
L = [b, 1, 3, 5, 5, hello, 7, z].
```

Here is what I currently have, however it seems to do the reverse of what I want, as it starts the list normally, and then reverses subsequent elements.

```
turn([],_,[]).
turn([H|T], L2, L) :-
   (   member(H, L2) ->
       L = [Reversed|H],
       reverse(Ln, Reversed),
       turn(T,L2, Ln);
   L = [H|L1],
   turn(T, L2, L1)).
```

The output is:

```
?- turn([1,2,3,4,5],[3], L).
L = [1,2,3,5,4].
```

Comment: Your actual results actually seem to match the description perfectly. Your description says, *When an element is a member of the toggle, it reverses order for all elements **after**.*. With that description, I would expect `turn([1,2,3,4,5],[3],L).` to result in `L = [1,2,3,5,4]`, not `L = [3,2,1,4,5]`. If you want `L = [3,2,1,4,5]` then the description should be, *When an element ins a member of the toggle, it reverses order for all elements **before**.*

Comment: Thank you. To specify, e elements of the first list are reversed until an elementis encountered that is in the second list. All elements after this element are included in the result list in unchanged order. When another element of the first list is encountered that is also in the second list, then the elements of the first list are reversed again.

Comment: You should edit your question to change the description. The code you wrote matches the original problem description. Also, what happens when more than one element of the first list is a member of the toggle list? That's a less trivial example you need to show so the problem is more fully understood.